# How Does ASP.NET Core/5 Integrate With IIS Express?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

I am troubleshooting why `IIS Express` cannot find my `web.config` after I moved my `ASP.NET` Core project.

> *(HTTP Error 500.19 - Cannot read configuration file - web.config file)*

My research revealed that most people were changing the **applicationhost.config** file. However, when I open my applicationhost.config file I only see what looks to be the default entry *(WebSite1 is not my project name)*:

```
<sites>
  <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
    <application path="/">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
  <siteDefaults>
    <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
    <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
  </siteDefaults>
  <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
  <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

I also understand that the **launchSettings.json** file has options that `IIS Express` uses. For example, I've changed my `localhost port` to `4444` in my `launchSettings.json` file:

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:4444",
    "sslPort": 0
  }
},
```

---

Before I moved my project, everything was working. Also, if I choose to run my project using "web" in `Visual Studio` (Kestrel I think), it works just fine even after the move.

So my question is how and/or where does my `ASP.NET` Core application set the specific settings for `IIS Express`? Of particular interest to me is how I can find and change the physical path to my project so that `IIS Express` can find my `web.config`.

Comment: Did you move the .vs hidden folder in your solution folder? The IIS Express config file is in that hidden folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When moving your project make sure to copy the root folder so that all files within the folder are included. It sounds like you just copied over the "src" folder which does not contain everything.

If you copy the root folder over and open the project it will run fine. As Lex Li noted above, there is a hidden folder called .vs which contains a config folder with applicationhost.config.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Joe and Lex! The hidden.vs folder was the key to my understanding. The path setting held the key to the solution.